# AWS Lambda Python Folder Structure

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a Python lambda that uses third party packages I installed with pip. I'm packaging it up as a zip and uploading it. The file structure looks like this:

```
pymysql/
   ___init___.py
   constants/
      ER.py
PyMySQL-1.0.2.dist-info/
   WHEEL
test-lambda.py
```

The problem is, when I upload that zip file, it flattens the folder structure out so my test-lambda.py file can't find the pymysql module anymore. The new folder structure after I upload it looks like this:

```
pymysql/___init___.py
pymysql/constants/ER.py
PyMySQL-1.0.2.dist-info/WHEEL
test-lambda.py
```

The names of the files have been replaced with the file paths. I thought this was just the way it represented folder structures at first, but I can create folders in the console and they're different. I'm building the lambda with terraform, here's the config:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
   function_name = "test-lambda"

   s3_bucket = "recipeapp-deployment-bucket"
   s3_key    = "test-lambda.zip"

   handler = "test-lambda.handleRequest"
   runtime = "python3.8"

   role = var.lambda_role_arn
}
```

Do I need to add something to the config to fix this?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Does your Lambda function fail to import the pymysql package at runtime? Or does it work fine, and you are you just questioning how the AWS Lambda console represents the package hierarchy?

Comment: I'm trying to fix the package import issue by fixing the folder hierarchy problem. When I put all the files into folders created within the lambda console, it detected the package.